# Link an account to another one

Tags: transactions

Is it possible to have an account which is linked to another. For example i have an account with `0` address and i have another one with `1` address, I want to if someone send bitcoin to `1`, the bitcoin go to `0`, and i want to it would be possible to me to see `1` transactions.

Answer (score 1):

I think solution for your use case is HD wallet where a bunch of keys is created from a single seed. There are 2 types of public/private key sets you can create with in HD wallets. Type 1 where you create sequence of keys with same seed. Type 2 where you can create a tree of keys using its branches and levels in your organisation or specific business. Type 2 below:

[image: Type 2]

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible.

What you can do is to manually sweep an address from it's WIF (wallet import format) using your wallet program, but you'll have to do this each time you want your bitcoin to be transfered to an address of your own.

Another possibility is to make a wallet with both addresses. I use electrum as wallet and it allows you to make a wallet importing addresses from one or more WIFs but you will not be able to create a security pass phrase for recovering your wallet in case you loose it.

Comment: No, I want to share many bitcoin address(in order to check who sent and how much sent), and people send bitcoin to them, and after that i have to send it back to my main address, but i don't wanna do that.

Comment: @zediziza why not using different addresses from your wallet program?

Comment: Because of fees. for many transactions, it would be so much for me to send it to my main account.

Comment: There is not so much you could do then, fees nowadays makes it more convenient to just use a single or very few addresses

Comment: I want to, but i want check who send how much, if i don't use different accounts for different people, how can i do that?

Comment: @zediziza don't send the bitcoins to your main address. There is no benefit in doing that. Besides address reuse is bad so you shouldn't be reusing your main address anyway. There should be no main address. Treat all addresses as disposable and for single use only.